# Random walks on connected finite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

On a finite connected graph if a random walked is choosing the next vertex uniformly at random from among the edges of its current vertex, then it looks quite obvious to me that given an infinite walk it can go from any vertex to another with probability $1$. One could very well use this property of such a random walker to define connectedness of a finite graph.

BUT, does there exist (or is there a need?) to come up with anymore formal a proof of this observation? (...it looks quite tautological to me!..)

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "it looks quite obvious to me that given an infinite walk it can go from any vertex to another with probability 1"? That each vertex has probability $1$ of occuring in the random walk, no matter what the first vertex is?

Comment: @user133281 Yes - that can be one meaning. Or one can also say that if one is given two specific vertices say $a$ and $b$ then with probability $1$ the random walker will reach $b$ from $a$ if allowed infinite steps.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straightforward to prove formally: Let $d$ be the diameter of the graph, the length of the longest shortest path between two vertices. Let $p = \frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is the number of vertices. Let $v$ be an arbitrary vertex. Then at each time point, there is at least a $p^d$ chance of reaching $v$ in $\leq d$ steps (since there is a path from our current point to $v$ of length at most $d$). This means that the probability that $v$ is not reached in the first $kd$ steps is at most $(1-p^d)^{k}$. This probability converges to $0$ for $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Can you kindly explain this idea of "diameter"?

Comment: See for instance http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html. In fact, we could also take $d=n$ as there is a path of length at most $n$ between any two vertices.

Comment: I was curious if there is a way to argue this using the idea of the Markov matrix $M$ where $M_{ij}$ is the probability of transition of the walker from vertex $j$ to $i$ i.e $1/deg(j)$. Then given an initial vertex $a$ and a final vertex $b$ and $n$, we have that $(M^n)_{ab}$ is the probability for the walker to go from $b$ to $a$ in $n$ steps. Now can one show that for $n\rightarrow \infty$ this matrix element tends to $1$?

Comment: There is a path of length at most $n-1$.

Comment: Sure, $n-1 < n$.